# Unable to view SQL Server 2005 System View Definitions

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to see the view definition for the system views sys.syslogins and sys.sysusers. I am a domain admin and logged on to the server as such. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following T-SQL to view the definition of syslogins.

```
USE Master
Go
sp_helptext 'sys.syslogins'
```

Replace 'sys.syslogins' with 'sys.sysusers' to see the definition of sysusers.

This, of course, assumes that your domain Admin userID has the appropriate rights within SQL Server.

sp_helptext is an inbuilt stored procedure that can be used to view the definitions of views and stored procedures within SQL Server databases.  For more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112%28SQL.90%29.aspx